# How to access make options in Makefile

Tags: makefile

I want to detect if "-s" is set in the Makefile command line. Is there a variable that captures make options that I can test?

For example, I want to do something like:

Makefile:

```
if ($(MAKE_OPTIONS), -s)
    #do something
endif
```

Invocation:

```
make $(MAKEFILE_OPTIONS) -C some_dir
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately it's tricky to find a really portable (across different releases of GNU make) way to do this.  Mark's solution gives false positives, if you have set any flag with an "s" in the name (e.g., `--warn-undefined-variables`).

In GNU make 4.0 and above, the layout of MAKEFLAGS is well-defined and you can use this:

```
$(findstring s,$(firstword -$(MAKEFLAGS))
```

to robustly and reliably tell if `-s` was given.  However this won't work reliably in versions of GNU make prior to 4.0.  You can use this:

```
$(findstring s,$(firstword -$(MAKEFLAGS)))$(filter -s,$(MAKEFLAGS))
```

This expands to the empty string if `-s` was not given, or a non-empty string if it was.  I believe that will work in all versions of GNU make.

Comment: Oh God, I forgot that you can have those long options.  Thank you Sir, may I have another!

Comment: And I did not notice 4.0 is released.  What planet have I been on?  Thank you Paul!

Comment: Some additional corner cases are lurking here; see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19521438/how-to-access-make-options-in-makefile/52131929#52131929 for details.

Answer (score 0):

The variable you're looking for is `MAKEFLAGS`.

```
ifeq ($(filter s, $(MAKEFLAGS)),s)
# do something
endif
```

Answer (score 0):

No, `filter` is not the one.  Use `findstring`:

```
ifneq ($(findstring s, $(MAKEFLAGS)),)
```

...

```
endif
```

or

```
$(if $(findstring s, $(MAKEFLAGS)),...)
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out there are even more corner cases for `MAKEFLAGS` that the below
function doesn't quite cover:

```
find_s = $(findstring s,$(firstword -$(MAKEFLAGS)))$(filter -s,$(MAKEFLAGS))
```

Consider the `Makefile` below that displays the value of `MAKEFLAGS`, both
inside and outside of a recipe, and the result of the `find_s` function:

```
find_s = $(findstring s,$(firstword -$(MAKEFLAGS)))$(filter -s,$(MAKEFLAGS))

$(info Outside a recipe, MAKEFLAGS="$(MAKEFLAGS)")
$(info $(if $(find_s),-s was detected,-s not found))

all:
    @echo 'Inside a recipe, MAKEFLAGS="$(MAKEFLAGS)"'
    @echo '$(if $(find_s),-s was detected,-s not found)'
```

This correctly detects the absence or presence of the flag `-s`, with or
without other single-character switches such as `-n`, e.g.:

```
$ make-3.81
Outside a recipe, MAKEFLAGS=""
-s not found
Inside a recipe, MAKEFLAGS=""
-s not found

$ make-4.1
Outside a recipe, MAKEFLAGS=""
-s not found
Inside a recipe, MAKEFLAGS=""
-s not found

$ make-3.81 -s
Outside a recipe, MAKEFLAGS="s"
-s was detected
Inside a recipe, MAKEFLAGS="s"
-s was detected

$ make-4.1 -s
Outside a recipe, MAKEFLAGS="s"
-s was detected
Inside a recipe, MAKEFLAGS="s"
-s was detected

$ make-3.81 -s -n
Outside a recipe, MAKEFLAGS="sn"
-s was detected
echo 'Inside a recipe, MAKEFLAGS="sn"'
echo '-s was detected'

$ make-4.1 -s -n
Outside a recipe, MAKEFLAGS="ns"
-s was detected
echo 'Inside a recipe, MAKEFLAGS="ns"'
echo '-s was detected'
```

One corner case is when `make` is invoked with "long" switches (starting with
`--`) in addition to multiple single-character switches.  These single-character
switches will be grouped together in a single word in `MAKEFLAGS` in Make 3.81:

```
$ make-3.81 -n -s --warn-undefined-variables
Outside a recipe, MAKEFLAGS=" --warn-undefined-variables -sn"
-s not found
echo 'Inside a recipe, MAKEFLAGS=" --warn-undefined-variables -sn"'
echo '-s not found'

$ make-4.1 -n -s --warn-undefined-variables
Outside a recipe, MAKEFLAGS="ns --warn-undefined-variables"
-s was detected
echo 'Inside a recipe, MAKEFLAGS="ns --warn-undefined-variables"'
echo '-s was detected'
```

The grouping of the switches means that the `$(filter -s,$(MAKEFLAGS))`
expression fails to detect `-s` with Make 3.81.

This can be fixed by changing `find_s` as follows:

```
find_s = $(findstring s,$(filter-out --%,$(MAKEFLAGS)))
```

Switches starting with `--` are filtered out, then the remaining content is
scanned for the desired switch (`s`), yielding correct detection:

```
$ make-3.81 -n -s --warn-undefined-variables
Outside a recipe, MAKEFLAGS=" --warn-undefined-variables -sn"
-s was detected
echo 'Inside a recipe, MAKEFLAGS=" --warn-undefined-variables -sn"'
echo '-s was detected'
```

An additional corner case crops up within recipes when variable assignments are
passed on the command-line (e.g., `make var=value`); in this case, the variable
`MAKEFLAGS` will additionally contain those variable assignments.  With
carefully chosen values, both versions of the detection logic `find_s` can still
be fooled, e.g.:

```
$ make-3.81 var='fake -s'
Outside a recipe, MAKEFLAGS=""
-s not found
Inside a recipe, MAKEFLAGS="var=fake\ -s"
-s was detected

$ make-4.1 var='fake -s'
Outside a recipe, MAKEFLAGS=""
-s not found
Inside a recipe, MAKEFLAGS=" -- var=fake\ -s"
-s was detected
```

The simplest cure for this second problem is to save off a copy of `MAKEFLAGS`
in another variable and use that within recipes, because fortunately outside of
recipes, `MAKEFLAGS` won't contain these variable assignments; otherwise, the
more complicated logic below will parse `MAKEFLAGS` and stop processing after it
encounters the words `=` or `--` while filtering out switches starting with
`--`:

```
empty :=
space := $(empty) $(empty)
# Define variable " " to avoid warnings with --warn-undefined-variables.
$(space) :=

parseFlags = $\
  $(if $(findstring =,$(firstword $1)),$\
       $(empty),$\
       $(if $(firstword $1),$\
            $(if $(filter-out --%,$(firstword $1)),$\
                 $(subst -,$(empty),$(firstword $1)))$\
            $(if $(filter-out --,$(firstword $1)),$\
                 $(call $0,$(wordlist 2,$(words $1),$1)))))

find_s = $(findstring s,$(call parseFlags,$(MAKEFLAGS)))
```

This new `find_s` correctly detects `-s` in all of the below situations:

```
$ make-3.81 var='fake -s'
Outside a recipe, MAKEFLAGS=""
-s not found
Inside a recipe, MAKEFLAGS="var=fake\ -s"
-s not found

$ make-4.1 var='fake -s'
Outside a recipe, MAKEFLAGS=""
-s not found
Inside a recipe, MAKEFLAGS=" -- var=fake\ -s"
-s not found

$ make-3.81 var='fake -s' -ns --warn-undefined-variables
Outside a recipe, MAKEFLAGS=" --warn-undefined-variables -sn"
-s was detected
echo 'Inside a recipe, MAKEFLAGS=" --warn-undefined-variables -sn -- var=fake\ -s"'
echo '-s was detected'

$ make-4.1 var='fake -s' -ns --warn-undefined-variables
Outside a recipe, MAKEFLAGS="ns --warn-undefined-variables"
-s was detected
echo 'Inside a recipe, MAKEFLAGS="ns --warn-undefined-variables -- var=fake\ -s"'
echo '-s was detected'
```

I'm hopeful that the above techniques work across a broad range of Make
versions, but with so many corner cases it's hard to tell; perhaps MadScientist
(GNU Make maintainer) can weigh in on this aspect.

Comment: My only comment is no doubt unsatisfying: people who care about this should just upgrade to some version of GNU Make >= 4.0, which was released over 10 years ago (I realize this answer was posted in 2018 but it's now 2024).  Then they don't have to worry about any of this and the answer I gave above will just work, in all cases.

Comment: I should also say, it would be good to understand WHY someone wants to detect whether `-s` was used or not.  I have a sneaking suspicion that this is an XY problem and maybe what is really needed is to read this blog post: https://make.mad-scientist.net/managing-recipe-echoing/  But, maybe there's a different reason that is not covered by that.

Answer (score 0):

This is an (updated June 2023) solution that can test for other single-letter flags too and works on GNU Make 3.81 through 4.4.1 (which broke some of the other approaches here). It won't work on anything older than 3.81 though since it uses `$(eval …)`.

As described in the comment it defines variables for the flags `-s`, `-k`, `-n` and `-q` named `$(make-s)`, `$(make-k)`, `$(make-n)` and `$(make-q)` respectively. The flags `-i`, `-r` and `-w` and maybe others too can be detected by extending the list in the `$(foreach ...)` function.

```
makeflags := $(firstword $(filter-out -,$(filter-out --%,$(MAKEFLAGS))))
define checkflags
  make-$1 := $(findstring $1,$(makeflags))
endef

# Define $(make-s), $(make-k), $(make-n) and $(make-q)
$(foreach flag,s k n q, $(eval $(call checkflags,$(flag))))

# Answer: Checking for -s:
$(if $(make-s), …silent case…, …noisy case…)
```

My test Makefile is:

```
makeflags := $(firstword $(filter-out -,$(filter-out --%,$(MAKEFLAGS))))
define checkflags
  make-$1 := $(findstring $1,$(makeflags))
endef
$(foreach flag,i r w s k n q, $(eval $(call checkflags,$(flag))))

$(info MAKEFLAGS = "$(MAKEFLAGS)")
$(foreach flag,i r w s k n q, \
    $(info make-$(flag) = "$(make-$(flag))" $(if $(make-$(flag)),YES,NO)))

all:
    @+echo 'all: MAKEFLAGS = "$(MAKEFLAGS)"'
    @+echo 'all: $(foreach f,i r w s k n q,$(make-$f))'
    @+echo ''
```